# Best approach for executing massive insert select from statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-performance

I have over 100k insert select from statements which I will break into smaller batches. I came up with two approaches and not sure which one is more effective. Please give me your thoughts.

I could use `APPEND` hint but I have to put a `Commit` after each insert statement due to ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel.

**Or**

I could remove the hint and go for a conventional path load with just one commit in the end of each batch load.

Conventional path load will definitely generate a lot of logs. But will committing after each insert statement be better or worse in terms of performance?

Comment: Committing after a single item insert is almost always 'bad' and will most definitely be slower because *it forces hardware-level synchronization* to ensure ACID. If the atomic level is the batch then use that as the transaction size. (Do note: I have no idea how [*nested transactions*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/gsg_xml_txn/java/nestedtxn.html) work in Oracle wrt. this problem.)

Comment: @user2864740 that's what I thought too. It makes no sense to commit after each transaction. But then if I go for the second option(commit after batch insert statements), db will generate a lot of logs due to conventional path load.

Comment: Does each statement only insert one row?  Are they mostly inserting into the same table?  For loading data through INSERTs, it's usually best to do something like `insert into some_table select ... from dual union all select ... from dual;`.

Comment: how many rows does each insert-select process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running all queries with a single commit will use a lot of log. And, if anything goes wrong, the rollback could be very expensive. So I'd discard that option.

And I'd start with one commit after each statement. Why? Because it is simple.

After running, if the process is too slow, add an ability to commit after some number of statements, every 1,000 statements seems a good place to start. You can then tweak that number to see where you get the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I had to export data from a sql server database to an oracle database. What I ended up doing was I used bcp to export the data from sql server to text files, then I used the Oracle SQL*Loader to import it to Oracle. Because the relation between tables was one to one, I wrote a little program that generated the ctl file for each table, and it also generated the entire script. The whole thing was very fast.

I am not sure if this works for you - it is not entirely clear from your post about the context, whether you want to write scripts, or it is a program that you are developing, or pl/sql...

Update: My advice to you was to import the data using text files and sql loader, that is if it is feasible. Without knowing all the details of what you are actually trying to do, it is hard to give the best answer. On the other hand you probably want an answer to your very specific question. You mentioned in one of the comments that you generated the script. If you want to go this path, you could generate commit statements every 500 or 1000 inserts. But again, stepping back, while there is nothing wrong per say with having a script with 100k insert statements, for performance reasons, I would not do it this way and I would rather pump the data using sql loader and text files. But that's just me.

Comment: They are just Insert into select statements.  I have 100k of these insert statements already generated. I will store them into files by 1000 statements per file. Then I will run these files.

Comment: @JohnAl: Do you insert the data from other tables in the same schema? Do you insert into one table or multiple tables? My advise is based on my experience. If I need to insert 100k+ rows in a table from an external source I would do it, as I said, using sql loader, and I wrote my answer under that assumption.  I would not create a sql script with 100k insert statements in it because it would be slow to execute. That might be not what you want to hear.